# Dictionary OrderBy Issue

Tags: c#, linux

I have a a dictionary which contains a list of unique numbers. The problem i am having is it will not go into the correct order. I am trying to order the dictionary in ascending order. The values in the dictionary are as follows:

[image]

The Code that i have to try and order this is

```
  foreach (var value in groupedDict.OrderBy(x => x.Key))
        {
```

When i run it in debug the order i get is
10, 100, 110, Ect rather than what you can see in the values in the dictionary should be 10, 15, 20.

Anyone any idea how i would get this to order ascending and what i am doing wrong.

Comment: What type is your Key? String or int?

Comment: Currently it is a string

Comment: The behavior described is clearly caused by a string key

Comment: It is string thats why it is not working...you have parse it into int

Comment: If you plan to change the Key to a different datatype then do it as soon as possible. Otherwise it will become increasingly difficult to change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your key is a string and you want a numeric sorting, try with this

```
foreach (var value in groupedDict.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.Key)))
```

Currently it is doing a string sort (which is giving you the unexpected results).

Answer (score 0):

Parse the string as an int?

```
foreach (var value in groupedDict.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.Key)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your Key is a string, the dictionary gets sorted by characters, not by numerical values.
You should convert in to int when sorting.

```
foreach (var value in groupedDict.OrderBy(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Key)))
    {
```